# Python transforming value to tuple

Tags: python, json

In python, I receive JSON data. The data looks like the following stub:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "naam": "4.13",
    "ruimte_temperatuur_sensor": {...},
     // etc
}
```

I map this json to an object (note the sensor is mapped already):

```
    ruimte = Ruimte(id=id,
                    naam=naam,
                    ruimte_temperatuur_sensor=temperatuur_sensor,
                    ruimte_humiditeit_sensor=humiditeit_sensor,
                    ruimte_beweging_sensor=beweging_sensor,
                    airco_temperatuur_sensor=airco_sensor,
                    radiator_temperatuur_sensor=radiator_sensor)
```

The strangest thing happens:

The `id` field in JSON is an integer, but Python maps it to a tuple. In my debugger, you can clearly see that the `id=id` maps to an integer, but then all of a sudden my object contains a tuple:

[image]

The object's constructor should not cause that:

```
class Ruimte:
    def __init__(self,
                 id: int,
                 naam: str,
                 ruimte_temperatuur_sensor: Sensor,
                 ruimte_humiditeit_sensor: Sensor,
                 ruimte_beweging_sensor: Sensor,
                 airco_temperatuur_sensor: Sensor,
                 radiator_temperatuur_sensor: Sensor):
        self.id = id,
        self.naam = naam,
        self.ruimte_temperatuur_sensor = ruimte_temperatuur_sensor
        self.ruimte_humiditeit_sensor = ruimte_humiditeit_sensor
        self.ruimte_beweging_sensor = ruimte_beweging_sensor
        self.airco_temperatuur_sensor = airco_temperatuur_sensor
        self.radiator_temperatuur_sensor = radiator_temperatuur_sensor
```

In the sub-objects the id is not parsed to a tuple, for exampe `ruimte.airco_temperatuur_sensor.id` is an integer:

[image]

but that JSON is parsed the same way:

```
def _parse_json_to_sensor(self, json: dict) -> Sensor:
    id = json["id"]
    type = SensorType(json["type"])
    meet_interval_sec = json["sensorInstelling"]["meetIntervalSec"]
    opslaan_interval_sec = json["sensorInstelling"]["opslaanIntervalSec"]

    sensor = Sensor(id=id,
                    type=type,
                    meet_interval_sec=meet_interval_sec,
                    opslaan_interval_sec=opslaan_interval_sec)
```

***I'm totally lost on this. What could cause this?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have commas after the lines where you assign `self.id` and `self.naam`. Remove them.

```
a_string = 'string',
type(a_string)
>>> tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma in the line:

```
self.id = id,
```

leads to the creation of a tuple. See this example:

```
a = 1

b = 1
c = 1,

print(b)
print(c)
```